# Can I define a log file's structure in laravel?

Tags: laravel, logging

I have tried to look everywhere but I can't find a solution. All I want to do is to create a default structure for the log file that is automatically generated by laravel and add a generic response according to the structure. For example I want my logs to maintain in a table that is automatically generated in a log file by default and all we have to do is write logs in that table?

Comment: You could try a custom formatter (as mentioned at https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/logging#creating-monolog-handler-channels)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to by pass laravels log facade which is a laravel wrapper for PHP monolog. So you can use monolog and write into the log file any way you like. Though I would recommend you have a really good reason for doing so because you may lose a bit of your laravel out of the box functionality.

Comment: is there any else way i can achieve my purpose?

Comment: Not that I know of that's out of the box with laravel. You either have to create a package service or find one.